Certificate not set or used by HTTP client in Azure Function
I have an Azure function where I created a HTTP client. This client need a certificate. That certificate is stored in Azure KeyVault. In the production environment I keep getting the following error in the Application Insights of the Azure function:
Message: Result: Function 'MyDummyFunction'
An exception was thrown by the invocation. Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
Here is how I am trying to set up the cert.
public class DummyHttpClient
{
    public readonly HttpClient client;

    private readonly ILogger<DummyHttpClient> logger;
    private readonly ActivationConfiguration configuration;

    public DummyHttpClient(ActivationConfiguration configuration, ILogger<DummyHttpClient> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.configuration = configuration;

        var handler = ClientHandlerConfigure();
        this.client = ClientConfigure(handler);
    }

    private HttpClientHandler ClientHandlerConfigure()
    {
        var certificate = GetCertificate();

        var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => { return true; },
        };

        if (certificateForBHN is not null)
        {
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    private HttpClient ClientConfigure(HttpClientHandler handler)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.ApiBaseAddress),
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100),
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

        return client;
    }

    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
            var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri($"https://dummykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());

            var certificateOptions = new DownloadCertificateOptions("Activation")
            {
                KeyStorageFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet,
            };

            var certificate = client.DownloadCertificate(certificateOptions);

            return certificate.Value;
    }
}


Does this code work locally? Because one of the default request headers is Content-Type.

yes it does actually

Does the server actually trust the client certificate Have you verified that the client cert is actually being retrieved from the GetCertificate function?

It is set, and tested the cert using Insomnia with the payload from the code, I got a response, locally everything is working.
I think right now, that when my class is getting instantiated, then the error is appearing, because it says that the invocation of the action actually fails.

I've followed below steps and able to run your code in Azure.
Code Snippet:
public class DummyHttpClient
{
    public readonly HttpClient client;

    private readonly ILogger<DummyHttpClient> logger;
    private readonly ActivationConfiguration configuration;

    public DummyHttpClient(ActivationConfiguration configuration, ILogger<DummyHttpClient> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.configuration = configuration;

        var handler = ClientHandlerConfigure();
        this.client = ClientConfigure(handler);
    }

    private HttpClientHandler ClientHandlerConfigure()
    {
        var certificate = GetCertificate();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
            ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, certChain, policyErrors) => true,
        };

        if (certificate != null)
        {
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        }

        return handler;
    }

    private HttpClient ClientConfigure(HttpClientHandler handler)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration.ApiBaseAddress),
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100),
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

        return client;
    }

    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        var client = new CertificateClient(new Uri("https://keyvault.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var certificateName = "certificate_name";
        var certificateWithPolicy = client.GetCertificate(certificateName);
        var downloadOptions = new DownloadCertificateOptions(certificateWithPolicy.Value.Name)
        {
            KeyStorageFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet,
        };
        var certificate = client.DownloadCertificate(downloadOptions);
       return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Value);
    }
}

Function Code:
public class Function1
{
   private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
   private readonly DummyHttpClient _dummyHttpClient;

   public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, DummyHttpClient dummyHttpClient)
   {
      _logger = logger;
      _dummyHttpClient = dummyHttpClient;
   }

[Function("Function1")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
  {
    var response = _dummyHttpClient.client.GetAsync("items");
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
   }
}

Enable System Identity in Azure function App:

Assign Key Vault Administrator and Key Vault Certificates Officer roles to the function app:

Portal:
2024-10-28T12:36:24Z [Information] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-10-28T12:36:24Z [Information] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
2024-10-28T12:36:24Z [Information] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=5848e8b2-c933-4056-a0c8-33a88d827180, Duration=3000ms)

Invocation Logs:

